# Python wrapper to pass arguments to bash

Tags: python, bash, shell, command-line-arguments

There is an application my company wrote (a little app to create CloudFormation templates) and passed the binary for all the teams to use.

In trying to automate this a bit I wrote a Python script that basically passes arguments to a Bash/Shell command. This is a wrapper so I am just making this so I can iterate over a bunch of config files to create CloudFormation stacks in AWS.

In shell, I would do

`cfapp cfn create -p Namespace=namespace -p Env=env -p Team=team -p Region=region --spec-file file://partner/foobar.yaml`

I wrote this in Python but I get a syntax error:

`os.system("cfapp cfn create -p Pool=%s" % pool "-p Namespace=%s" % namespace "-p Env=%s" % env "-p Team=%s" % team "-r %s" % region "--spec-file file://partner/"+str(config)+".yaml")
      time.sleep(5)`

I read that this was how to do it via python though, obv, my implementation is wrong.

Comment: use only one percent and group arguments together in a `tuple` at the end of the string... Even better: use `subprocess` module with a list of arguments, don't attempt to create the command line yourself.

Comment: ah `tuple` makes a lot of sense - thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: Not sure if I missed something, but is there a reason why you don't just use all bash?

Answer (score 3):

Use `subprocess` instead:

```
subprocess.check_call([
    "cfapp", "cfn", "create",
    "-p", "Namespace=%s" % namespace,
    "-p", "Env=%s" % env,
    "-p", "Team=%s" % team,
    "-p", "Region=region",
    "--spec-file", spec_file,
])
```

---

In terms of your initial error, your string formatting syntax is incorrect:

```
>>> pool = "foo"
>>> namespace = "bar"
>>> "cfapp cfn create -p Pool=%s" % pool "-p Namespace=%s" % namespace
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    "cfapp cfn create -p Pool=%s" % pool "-p Namespace=%s" % namespace
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> "cfapp cfn create -p Pool=%s -p Namespace=%s" % (pool, namespace)
'cfapp cfn create -p Pool=foo -p Namespace=bar'
```

Comment: why subprocess as opposed to optparse? It does look nicer - just curious.

Comment: @Claudiu: `subprocess.check_call` is better if you don't care about retrieving the output/error streams.

Comment: ah, I misunderstood. OK. I was using os.system but I'll switch to Subprocess. Thanks .